# Can SCM-Manager prefill my newly created repositories with a template?

Tags: repository, scmmanager

Many of my projects have the same directory structure. When creating a new project I would like to have that structure set up right away.

My projects are managed by SCM-Manager.

Is there a way to have SCM-Manager create my directory structure from a template when I create a new repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this is not possible. Maybe this can be implemented by writing a plugin. There already exists a feature request (for subversion but should be possible for all repo types) at https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/issue/241/creating-repositories-with-standard where you can vote for.